# in openLayers,how to draw a sector with a point ,radius,radian

Tags: javascript, openlayers

in openLayers,how to draw a sector with a point ,radius,radian

if provide the example code , excellent

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: sorry，i got confused,you mean what?